# Can Smaug melt the One Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-one-ring

From  The Lord of the Rings, The Fellowship of the Ring, "*The Shadow of the Past*", we know that Gandalf told Frodo:

> there is not now any dragon left on earth in which the old fire is hot
>   enough [to melt the Rings of Power]

So my question is this:

**Can Smaug melt the One Ring?**

If he breathed fire on Bilbo while they were talking, would the One Ring have been destroyed?

Comment: I can't help but appreciate the irony!  http://i.imgur.com/jVu780S.png

Comment: @JacobRaccuia - that is pretty much opposite of irony.

Comment: Probably "appreciate the coincidence".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No, he can't. While some dragons had breath hot enough to melt the lesser rings of power, Gandalf says:

> [...], nor was there ever any dragon, not even Ancalagon the Black,
>   who could have harmed the One Ring, the Ruling Ring, for that was made
>   by Sauron himself.

Adding source and larger quote for context.

It is established that Mount Doom is the only practical possibility. LOTR I.2 (when Gandalf verifies that Frodo's ring is the Ring and tells Frodo what that means):

> But there is no smith's forge in this Shire that could change it at all. Not even the anvils and furnaces of the Dwarves could do that. It has been said that dragon-fire could melt and consume the Rings of Power, but there is not now any dragon left on earth in which the old fire is hot enough; nor was there ever any dragon, not even Ancalagon the Black, who could have harmed the One Ring, the Ruling Ring, for that was made by Sauron himself. There is only one way: to find the Cracks of Doom in the depths of Orodruin, the Fire-mountain, and cast the Ring in there.

(Several of the Seven were destroyed by dragons.)

Comment: About the last sentence: where is it described that other rings were destroyed by dragons?

Comment: In _The Fellowship of the Ring_, Gandalf also says "Seven the Dwarf-kings possessed, but three he has recovered, and the others the dragons have consumed."

Comment: Of course, all that is just _what Gandalf and Elrond think_. The dragons were created by _Morgoth_ himself, so I can't really see from what Gandalf deduces Sauron's Ring would necessarily be immune.

Comment: I wonder if a fusion reactor would melt it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sauron was the servant and pupil of Melkor. He learned a great deal from him. One would assume he would have understood the power that was given to dragon fire and made the ring to be resistant to it. Furthermore, being essentially kin to Sauron and Melkor, Gandalf would probably have known all of this and (along with some deeper wisdom and insight) have been able to make a reasonable assumption

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The dragons are Maiar, I don't think Melkor created them.

Comment: @einpoklum: [nope, the dragons were not Maiar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urul%C3%B3ki#History). You may be confusing them with Balrogs.

Comment: @James Christopher - nope, in The Fellowship of the Ring, Gandalf says "The Ring contains neither proton nor neutron, and is bound not by particle physics as we understand it.".

Comment: @einpoklum - did you get that from a David Day book?  You need to read this: http://tolkien.slimy.com/essays/DayBooks.html

Comment: @BradWerth - I had no idea that Gandalf was so well-versed in 20th century science.

Comment: Does the lava that destroys the Ring have to be inside Mt. Doom, or could you bore a hole deep into the earth's crust and destroy it in the magma there?  Sooner or later it might end up as lava inside of Mt. Doom.

Answer (score 7):

It's mentioned multiple times throughout the story that The One Ring can only be destroyed in the 'fires from whence it was forged'.  I believe that perhaps other Rings of Power may be melt-able by Smaug, but likely NOT the One Ring.